# How to call the run method from another class?

Tags: java, methods, call

Sorry, if this is a stupid question.

I would like to find out how to call the run method that is located in

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FereastraPrincipala().setVisible(true);
```

from the class AdaugaComanda.java.

The run method is declared in FereastraPrincipala.java and I want to call this from AdaugaComanda.java, so that changes can be seen to FereastraPrincipala after introducing values in the textfields from AdaugaChitanta.java. If I don't call a method, then I have to run FereastraPrincipala.java again, in order to see the new info in the JTabbedPane.

Here is the code for FereastraPrincipala.java

```
 package sakila.ui;

 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Vector;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import sakila.entity.*;
 import sakila.util.HibernateUtil;

public class FereastraPrincipala extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public FereastraPrincipala() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    AdaugaComanda ac = new AdaugaComanda();
    ac.setVisible(true);
}                                          

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new FereastraPrincipala().setVisible(true);
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    try{

    List<Comanda> comenzi = session.createQuery("from Comanda").list();

    Vector<String> tableHeaders = new Vector<String>();
    Vector tableData = new Vector();
    tableHeaders.add("IdComanda");
    tableHeaders.add("Depozit");
    tableHeaders.add("Furnizor");
    tableHeaders.add("Client");
    tableHeaders.add("Produs");
    tableHeaders.add("Cantitate");
    tableHeaders.add("Unit de mas");

    for (Comanda comanda : comenzi) {
        Vector <Object> oneRow = new Vector <Object>();
        oneRow.add(comanda.getIdcomanda());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getDepozit() == null ? "" : comanda.getDepozit().toString());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getFurnizor() == null ? "" : comanda.getFurnizor().toString());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getClient() == null ? "" : comanda.getClient().toString());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getProdus() == null ? "" : comanda.getProdus().toString());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getCantitate());
        oneRow.add(comanda.getUnitmas());

        tableData.add(oneRow);

        }
   ComandaTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders));    

       }catch (Exception he){
        he.printStackTrace();
    }
 }                              
    });
}
```

}

Here is the code for AdaugaComanda.java

```
   package sakila.ui;

  import java.io.EOFException;
  import java.util.List;
  import sakila.entity.*;
  import sakila.service.Functie;
  import sakila.entity.Client;

 public class AdaugaComanda extends javax.swing.JDialog {

public AdaugaComanda() {
    initComponents();
    initComboBoxes();
}

   private void initComboBoxes() {

    DepozitComboBox.removeAllItems();
    FurnizorComboBox.removeAllItems();
    ClientComboBox.removeAllItems();
    ProdusComboBox.removeAllItems();

    System.out.println("sterge itemurile");

    List<Depozit> depozite = (List<Depozit>) sakila.client.Client.citeste(Functie.LISTEAZA_DEPOZITE);
    for (Depozit depozit : depozite)
        DepozitComboBox.addItem(depozit);

    List<Furnizor> furnizori = (List<Furnizor>) sakila.client.Client.citeste(Functie.LISTEAZA_FURNIZORI);
    for (Furnizor furnizor : furnizori)
        FurnizorComboBox.addItem(furnizor);

    List<Client> clienti = (List<Client>) sakila.client.Client.citeste(Functie.LISTEAZA_CLIENTI);
    for (Client client : clienti)
        ClientComboBox.addItem(client);

    List<Produs> produse = (List<Produs>) sakila.client.Client.citeste(Functie.LISTEAZA_PRODUSE);
    for (Produs produs : produse)
        ProdusComboBox.addItem(produs);
    System.out.println("adaugaitemuri"); 

}

private void ClientComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                              

private void InsereazaButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    runQueryBasedOnInsert();
}                                               

 private void runQueryBasedOnInsert(){

    Comanda comanda = new Comanda();

    Depozit depozit = (Depozit)DepozitComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    comanda.setDepozit(depozit);

    Furnizor furnizor = ((Furnizor)FurnizorComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    comanda.setFurnizor(furnizor);

    sakila.entity.Client client = ((sakila.entity.Client)ClientComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    comanda.setClient(client);

    Produs produs = ((Produs)ProdusComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    comanda.setProdus(produs);

    comanda.setCantitate(Integer.parseInt(CantitateTextField.getText()));
    comanda.setUnitmas(UnitMasTextField.getText());

    sakila.client.Client.scrie(Functie.CREAZA_COMANDA, comanda);
```

}

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new AdaugaComanda().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe someone could help me. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Seeing that you changed your question, 
is FereastraPrincipala a JFrame?

Comment: FereastraPrincipala is a JFrame and it means main window and AdaugaChitanta is a JDialog, where I insert values, that are persisted in the database. From FereastraPrincipala.java I can open AdaugaChitanta, in order to make changes to the database. But I can't see the changes in the JTabbedPane of FereastraPrincipala, only if I run FereastraPrincipala.java one more time and that's why I wanted to see the changes directly after closing the JDialog AdaugaChitanta. I hope I wasn't vague with my explanation.

Comment: And in order to see them, I have to call from AdaugaChitanta a method (the content that must be called is in the run() method) that is located in FereastraPrincipala, so that the changes can be seen after inserting the values in AdaugaChitanta.java.

Comment: Did you see my update? This should have been clarified earlier :)
I suggest you look at Data Transfer Objects

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Answer (score 3):

You could make FereastraPrincipala a member variable of AnduagaChitanta.

```
public class  AnduagaChitanta
{
  FereastraPrincipala fPrincipala  = new FereastraPrincipala (); //Or inject it into the constructor

  private void SomeMethod()
  {
   fPrincipala.run();
  }
}
```

in the run method()

```
public void run()
{
  setvisible(true);
}
```

If you are wondering how to inject it:

public class  AnduagaChitanta
    {
      FereastraPrincipala fPrincipala

```
  public AnduagaChitanta(FereastraPrincipala fPrinicipala)
  {
      this.fPrinicipala = fPrinicipala;
  }
  private void SomeMethod()
  {
   fPrincipala.run();
  }
}
```

If you like you can make FereastraPrincipala  implement an interface so the definition of the constructor can be:

public AnduagaChitanta(ISomethingPrinicipala fPrinicipala)

But now we are going into design patterns so I will leave it at that.

**Update**
After your update I would do something like this:

```
FereastraPrincipala extends JFrame implements Runnable 
{
   public void run()
   {
        setvisible(true) ;
   } 

}
```

I don't know where but maybe in your AnduagaChitanta class I would do this

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(fPrinicpala) 
}
```

I hope that makes sense

Comment: It's been a while since I did Java. But it should be more or less right

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. I am very thankful, although I don't know if your explanation matches my code. I am a beginner with Java and maybe it's not an excellent question. I reedited my question and it gives all the details. If you can figure out, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Never call `run()` method of thread. It executes in the current thread it self !! Always call `start()` method. Coming to your case, create a new class so that you could invoke `start()` on it from other places